# Ninja slider pause slideshow with thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I'm using this slider for my website

http://www.menucool.com/slider/flickr-like-slideshow

I'm having problem with the play/pause slider function.
The thumbnail and the images above is separate, both have their own js.
There are button to pause the slideshow and thumbnail separately.

I have to click to pause the slideshow, and click another button to pause the thumbnails.

Any method to combine the two button?

So that no need to click twice to pause the slider.

```
<div id="ninja-slider" class="myslider">
    <div>
        <div class="slider-inner">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a class="ns-img" href="img/image1.jpg"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="ns-img" href="img/image2.jpg"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="ninja-slider-pause-play"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="thumbnail-slider">
            <div class="inner">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" href="img/image1.jpg"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" href="img/image2.jpg"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div id="ninja-slider-pause-play"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ninja Slider js

```
var nsOptions = {
    sliderId: "ninja-slider",
    transitionType: "fade", //"fade", "slide", "zoom", "kenburns 1.2" or "none"
    autoAdvance: true, //If autoAdvance is required, don't set this to true. You can set the autoAdvance of the Thumbnail Slider to true because the "before" callback function listed below has been set to let this slider to be driven by the Thumbnail Slider.
    delay: "default",
    transitionSpeed: 600,
    aspectRatio: "2:1",
    initSliderByCallingInitFunc: false,
    shuffle: false,
    startSlideIndex: 0, //0-based
    navigateByTap: false,
    keyboardNav: false,
    before: function (currentIdx, nextIdx, manual) { if (manual && typeof mcThumbnailSlider != "undefined") mcThumbnailSlider.display(nextIdx); },
    license: "b2e98"
};
```

Thumbnail Slider Js

```
var thumbnailSliderOptions = {
    sliderId: "thumbnail-slider",
    orientation: "horizontal",
    thumbWidth: "138px",
    thumbHeight: "110px",
    showMode: 3,
    autoAdvance: true,
    selectable: true,
    slideInterval: 3000,
    transitionSpeed: 700,
    shuffle: false,
    startSlideIndex: 0, //0-based
    pauseOnHover: true,
    initSliderByCallingInitFunc: false,
    rightGap: null,
    keyboardNav: true,
    mousewheelNav: true,
    before: function (currentIdx, nextIdx, manual) { if (typeof nslider != "undefined") nslider.displaySlide(nextIdx); },
    license: "b2e98"
};
```

Comment: This is the link for main slider
http://www.menucool.com/slider/ninja-slider/4/ninja-slider.js

Comment: This is the link for thumbnail slider
http://www.menucool.com/slider/ninja-slider/4/thumbnail-slider.js

Comment: where is your slider link?

Comment: @SagarKodte https://fiddle.jshell.net/ycLk3xzt/2/ I having problem in import the ninja-slider js to fiddle

Comment: I have multiple slider so I can't use ID for each (can't dupplicate ID). How can I use class to replace it?